# Capture elements with Selenium which are loaded lazy in Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Trying to click a button with `Selenium`, but I keep getting an error:

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate
> element: {"method":"link text","selector":"AGREE"}

Here's the button I am trying to click.

[image]

I assume, the popup is loaded lazy. I found some sources, but could not make it work. Here's my code

```
import pandas as pd
import bs4
import selenium as sel
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time
import os

driver = sel.webdriver.Chrome() #uses Chrome driver in usr/bin/ from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
url = 'https://fbref.com/en/squads/0cdc4311/Augsburg'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
html = driver.page_source
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

#click button -> accept cookies
element = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "AGREE")
element.click()

>>> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"AGREE"}
```

I also tried

```
[...]
driver = sel.webdriver.Chrome() #uses Chrome driver in usr/bin/ from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds'
[...]
```

and the popup is definitively there. But still get the same error.

Comment: I see no accept cookies element there.

Comment: Mhhh, probably some geographical specific problem to reproduce? I added a screenshot and a missing line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What happens?

You try to select a `<button>` via `.LINK_TEXT, "AGREE"`, what won't work, cause it is a `<button>` not a link.

#### How to fix?

Wait for the `<button>` selected by `xpath` to be clickable:

```
#click button -> accept cookies
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[text()="AGREE"]')))
element.click()
```

Comment: Found out a couple of minutes ago. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Would you help me one more time? If I do `element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Get table as CSV (for Excel)"]')` and `element.click()` I get `Message: element not interactable`

Comment: Of course SO is happy to help you with this, but to keep question / answer clean - This would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70381289/clicking-button-with-selenium-not-working