# Clicking button with Selenium not working

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

https://fbref.com/en/squads/0cdc4311/Augsburg-Stats provides buttons to transform a table to csv, which I would like to scrape. I click the buttons like

```
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Get table as CSV (for Excel)"]')
for element  in elements:
    element.click()
```

but I get an exception

> ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

This is the element I am trying to click.
[image]

Here's the full code (I added Adblock plus as a Chrome extension, which should be configured to test locally):

```
import pandas as pd
import bs4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import os

#activate adblock plus
path_to_extension = '/home/andreas/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb/3.11.4_0'
options = Options()
options.add_argument('load-extension=' + path_to_extension)

#uses Chrome driver in usr/bin/ from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

#wait and switching back to tab with desired source
time.sleep(5) 
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])

NO_OF_PREV_SEASONS = 5

df = pd.DataFrame()

urls = ['https://fbref.com/en/squads/247c4b67/Arminia-Stats']

for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    #click button -> accept cookies
    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="AGREE"]')
    element.click()
    
    for i in range(NO_OF_PREV_SEASONS):
        elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Get table as CSV (for Excel)"]')
        for element  in elements:
            element.click()
        
        #todo: get data
        
        #click button -> navigate to next page
        time.sleep(5)
        element = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Previous Season")
        element.click()
    
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`button` is inside the drop-down list (i.e. `<span>Share & Export</span>`) so you need to hover it first.

e.g.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

action_chain = ActionChains(driver)
hover = driver.find_element_by_xpath("// span[contains(text(),'Share & Export')]")
action_chain.move_to_element(hover).perform()      # hover to show drop down list
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 200)")   # scroll down a bit
time.sleep(1)                                      # wait for scrolling
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("// button[contains(text(),'Get table as CSV (for Excel)')]")
action_chain.move_to_element(button).click().perform()  # move to button and click
time.sleep(3)
```

output:
[image]

Comment: On `actions.move_to_element(element).perform()` I am getting `MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: move target out of bounds`

Comment: That's weird. I ran it perfectly. So maybe you need to move `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 200)")` and `time.sleep(1)`  before `actions.move_to_element(element).perform()` in order to scroll down before hovering.

Answer (score 0):

This also happens to me sometimes. One way to overcome this problem is by getting the X and Y coordinates of this button and clicking on it.

```
import pyautogui
    for element  in elements:
        element_pos = element.location
        element_size = element.size
        x_coordinate, y_coordinate = elemnt_pos['x'], element_pos['y']
        e_width, e_height = element_size['width'], element_size['height']
        click_x = x_coordinate + e_width/2
        click_y = y_coordinate + e_height/2
        pyauotgui.click(click_x, click_y)
```

Other solution that you may try is to click on the tag that contains this button.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here:

1. You have to click and open Share and Export tab and then click Get table as CSV button
2. You have to scroll the page to access the non-first tables.
   So, your code can be something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import bs4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import os

#activate adblock plus
path_to_extension = '/home/andreas/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb/3.11.4_0'
options = Options()
options.add_argument('load-extension=' + path_to_extension)
options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")

#uses Chrome driver in usr/bin/ from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

#wait and switching back to tab with desired source
time.sleep(5) 
#driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])

NO_OF_PREV_SEASONS = 5

df = pd.DataFrame()

urls = ['https://fbref.com/en/squads/247c4b67/Arminia-Stats']

for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    #click button -> accept cookies
    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="AGREE"]')
    element.click()
    
    for i in range(NO_OF_PREV_SEASONS):
        elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='section_heading_text']//li[@class='hasmore']")
        for element  in elements:
            actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
            time.sleep(0.5)
            element.click()
            wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@tip='Get a link directly to this table on this page']"))).click()

            #todo: get data
```

Comment: Same here: on `actions.move_to_element(element).perform()` I am getting `MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: move target out of bounds`

Comment: That's not the same. On what iteration do you see this error?

Comment: Sorry, with same I meant the solution provided above. It's weird it happens on the first iteration?!

Comment: OK, try setting the window size to big enough as I set here. Let me know if now it works for the first iteration

Comment: Also I'm not sure you should use `driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])` here.

Comment: What do you mean with that?

Comment: You do not have to switch to any window, there is a single window only at the beginning

Comment: Ok. On my screen it opens a second tab installing Adblock Plus.